# How do we formally describe mathematical modelling using set theory?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-modeling

Suppose I have a bag with a pouch of few items : pen, pencil, eraser etc, and I want to mathematical model the idea of things existing in my pouch using ZFC, is that actually possible?

The doubt raised when I read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4384000/688539), in it, it is said that every other set in ZFC are generated out of the axioms which confirm existence of some sets ( power set axiom, empty set axiom etc etc).

Hence, except of the sets generated out of the axioms, we can't insert sets of our liking to be described by the theory. So, what additional structure/ theory do we need to describe the procedure of lifting up what we see in reality into something which can be described by set theory?)

Comment: $\mathsf {ZFC}$ is about mathematical objects: numbers, functions, spaces.

Comment: What is "applied" set theory? Consider a bag with eggs and a beg with apples: what will be the "union" of the two bags? and their "intersection"? So-called "naive" set theory will give you answers.

Comment: Were all the highschool textbook examples wrong?! @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted -- there is a perfectly sensible question hereabouts that beginners naturally ask. Early set theories made room for applications by allowing urelements (likewise for high school "new math" talk of sets). So why do we now concentrate on 'pure' set theories in maths courses?

Comment: Why? I'm not saying that... In the above example, the intersection will be the empty set and the union will be a bag with eggs and apples. But what do you expect? A $\mathsf {ZFC}$'s theorem proving that eggs exist? and - if so - how they can be "manufactured" starting from the empty et?

Comment: As silly as it sounds, yeah, something around those lines. It's like I don't understand how to incoporate the real life things into ZFC such that I can talk about them using ZFC

Comment: See e.g. [Set theory with *urelements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Urelements_in_set_theory): it means to start from a "zero-layer" of objects that are **not** sets (e.g. natural numbers) and apply to it the hierarchical construction of sets using $\mathsf {ZFC}$ axioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ZFC, the only set which doesn't have only other sets as its members is the empty set. There are no sets which have as their members widgets, wombats or other non-sets.

Now you might suppose that it is more natural to think of set theory as a *superstructure* we can add to theories about other things. So then, starting perhaps from some given urelements -- i.e. elements which don't themselves have members -- we can form sets of them, and then sets of sets, sets of sets of sets, and so on and on. This indeed is how early set theorists originally thought of sets. (Likewise, more informally, think of schoolroom use of set talk in "new math").

However, for purely mathematical purposes such as reconstructing analysis, it seems that we only need a single non-membered base-level entity, and it is tidy to think of this as the empty set. So for internal mathematical purposes, we can take the whole universe of sets to contain only 'pure' sets (when we dig down and look at the members of members of ... members of sets, we find nothing other than more sets). Hence, for most mathematical purposes, we concentrate on 'pure' set theories like ZFC.

But what if we want to be able to apply our set-theoretic apparatus in talking about e.g. sets of widgets or wombats or (more seriously!) space-time points? Then it might seem that we will want the base level of non-membered  elements to be populated with  those widgets, wombats or space-time points as the case might be. However, we can always *code* for widgets, wombats or space-time points using some kind of numbers, and we can treat those numbers as sets. So our set-theory-for-applications can *still* involve only pure sets. That's why typical introductions to set theory either explicitly restrict themselves to talking about pure sets, or -- after officially allowing the possibility of urelements -- promptly ignore them.

[Excerpted in part from [Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide]](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl)

Comment: Wombats as numbers O_o?

Comment: This answer is well written and should probably be accepted, but in my opinion the fact that we don't deal with things like "the set of all items in my bag" in mathematical set theory does not really have that much to do with urelements. Rather, it has to do with the fact that this set would change from one moment to the other and that it is only vaguely defined. (What counts as an item? What counts as inside rather than outside? Why am I counting the pen as a single item rather than counting the cap and the body of the pen separately?) One can hardly do mathematics with such "sets".

Comment: Let me rephrase slightly: the answer correctly states that if urelements are excluded, then there can be no "set of all items in my bag". However, even if urelements are allowed, still this "set of all items in my bag" is not really an object that's amenable to mathematical study.

Comment: So school room "new maths" isn't maths at all? Not interesting maths, we can agree.

Comment: @PeterSmith I would say it's related to rigorous maths in the same way naive set theory is related to rigorous maths, and what you describe in your answer is how to translate naive claims made in highschool set theory classrooms into rigorous set theoretical claims (whether one does that with urelements or without them). I am not familiar with the history of urelements in set theory, but I have always taken them to be abstract objects, not concrete, physical objects. If I am mistaken about that, I would be happy to be corrected!